# Where is the external IP of my kubernetes node?

Tags: kubernetes

I deploy a 3 nodes k8s cluster on my local virtualbox. But I cannot find the external IP of the nodes:

```
kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep IP
2017-11-11 22:36:06.346458 I | proto: duplicate proto type registered: google.protobuf.Any
2017-11-11 22:36:06.346701 I | proto: duplicate proto type registered: google.protobuf.Duration
2017-11-11 22:36:06.346743 I | proto: duplicate proto type registered: google.protobuf.Timestamp
      type: InternalIP
      type: InternalIP
      type: InternalIP
```

Reading up online and I cannot get the external IP if I don't deploy the cluster with the public cloud provider...Is there a workaround for that?

I would like to try service and ingress locally without going thru the provide cloud provider setup.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the IP is exposed in the yaml file. You could do:

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried and it doesn't work:

k8s1      Ready     1d        v1.7.3+coreos.0   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS   4.4.0-62-generic